KMP - Parsing date/time string in iOS module has rounding error in nanoseconds
I am building an expect/actual implementation of DateTime handling in a Kotlin multiplatform project, and having an issue with the iOS side. When I create an NSDateFormatter with a dateFormat string of hh:mm:ss.SSS a, which uses milliseconds, it often ends up being off by 1 millisecond. As you can see in my code below, I call the dateFromString() function on the NSDateFormatter instance and pull the individual values from that.
This code works with a DateTime String value of "05:34:09.123 AM", but fails with a String value of "05:34:09.456 AM" (different millisecond value). If I print the values from this code when testing both of the previously mentioned DateTime Strings, I get the following:
DateFormatUtil: stringValue:05:34:09.123 AM, nanoseconds: 123000025, millisecond: 123
DateFormatUtil: stringValue:05:34:09.456 AM, nanoseconds: 455999970, millisecond: 455

Here is the code for parsing the DateTime Strings (the pattern is a constructor param):
private val dateFormat = NSDateFormatter().apply {
        dateFormat = pattern
}

...

actual fun fromString(stringValue: String): DateTest {
        dateFormat.dateFromString(stringValue)?.let { nsDate ->
            val nsCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar
            val year = nsCalendar.component(NSCalendarUnitYear, nsDate)
            val month = nsCalendar.component(NSCalendarUnitMonth, nsDate)
            val day = nsCalendar.component(NSCalendarUnitDay, nsDate)
            val hour = nsCalendar.component(NSCalendarUnitHour, nsDate)
            val minute = nsCalendar.component(NSCalendarUnitMinute, nsDate)
            val second = nsCalendar.component(NSCalendarUnitSecond, nsDate)
            val nanosecond = nsCalendar.component(NSCalendarUnitNanosecond, nsDate)
            /*
            * Convert nanosecond to millisecond
            * There is a rounding issue here for some reason.
            * The nanosecond value is usually around ~25 nanoseconds off,
            * either higher or lower than the expected value.
            * If it's lower, then the millisecond value will be
            * rounded down and end up off by 1.
             */
            val millisecond = nanosecond / 1_000_000
            return DateTest(year.toInt(), month.toInt(), day.toInt(), hour.toInt(), minute.toInt(), second.toInt(), millisecond.toInt())
        }
        return DateTest()
    }

I've tried several different millisecond values, and haven't found much rhyme or reason to when the nanosecond value is higher or lower than the actual value.
If anyone has an idea of how to get this to parse that millisecond value correctly, I'm all ears.
